# ld: 81 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am required to add the `-ObjC` flag into `other linker flags`.

When I now run the project on a simulator, everything is smooth. However, when I run it on a real/generic device, I get the following error in the log:

```
ld: 81 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

I am well aware that this issue has been addressed over and over on the SO but none of the answers have resolved mine.

Here's what I have already done:

- changed `GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS` to NO
- enable `ENABLE_TESTABILITY` to NO
- did not import any `.m` instead of `.h` file
- I am unable to view the source code to try remove the duplicates

I was thinking perhaps there's a way to limit a flag in `other linker flags` to a specific framework? so that the linker won't perform it on all frameworks?

I am pretty clueless on this matter. Help would be highly Appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i used an alternative flag called `-force_load framework.a` which is similar to `-ObjC` except, you apply it to a specific framework rather than `-ObjC` that applies to the entire target and can crteate the implications I had.